# File Download on Javascript does not work on firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox

have written this piece of code which is working perfect on Google Chrome but not working on Firefox, do you have a clue?

The expected behavior is that you pass as parameters a xml text and a name and it downloads a xml file with that xml text and with the name you sent, as I said, for chrome is ok but for firefox, it does not download it.

/**
 * Creates and download a file from a selected row on query results
 * @param xmltext 
 * @param filename
 */

function createAndDownloadFile(xmltext, filename){

```
var pom = document.createElement('a');
//creates a blob variable with the xml text
var bb = new Blob([xmltext], {type: 'text/xml'});

//sets the atribute href
pom.setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(bb));
pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

//creates the download url
pom.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/xml', pom.download, pom.href].join(':');
pom.draggable = true; 
pom.classList.add('dragout');

//apply the click on to download the file
pom.click();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem that was just answered for me here on stackoverflow: [Download attribute not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115748/download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox)

Try adding the element to the DOM before the click event:

```
//apply the click on to download the file
document.body.appendChild(pom);
pom.click();
document.body.removeChild(pom);
```

Comment: Hello MattSidor Works just perfect for me, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Can you do me a favor and click the green check mark to the left of my answer, to tell others that it answered your question? Thanks much!